# Insert dynamic list to data base C# using multi thread

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, asynchronous, insert

How could we synchronously insert data from a list in database with a thread when another thread is full filling the list

Comment: use a lock and for instead of foreach

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the [tour], and read through the [help]. You can also read about [ask] a good question and how to write a [mcve]

Comment: you can use threadsafe collections https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx